# How can I click confirm window using selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I want to click confirm window using selenium.

So I tried this code

```
if driver.find_element_by_class_name('sa-confirm-button-container') == True:
            no_map.click()
 else:

            source = driver.page_source
            bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

            price_list.append(bs.select('#infoJiga'))
```

I want to know is there 'sa-confirm-button-container' class in html source.(This means there is confirm window.)

If there is class name in source, I want to click confirm-box.

Can you help me?

Comment: `find_element_by_class_name` returns a WebElement, not a boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sa-confirm-button-container'))>0
```

Answer (score 0):

> `if driver.find_element_by_class_name('sa-confirm-button-container') == True`

this won't work.

Why not just:

```
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sa-confirm-button-container')
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('oops, no element')
```